# How to make a bash script fail based on grep regex?

Tags: bash, grep

I have the following bash script.

The problem I try to solve is really easy. When a commit in Git no starts with `gh-1234 ...` it should fail.

What is wrong with this bash script?

```
commit_regex='(gh-[0-9]+|merge)'

error_msg="Aborting commit. Your commit message is missing either a Github Issue ('gh-1111') or 'Merge'."

if ! grep -q "$commit_regex" <<< "$1"; then
    echo "$error_msg" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: I think you want `grep -E`?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to do `grep -E "$commit_regex"`

From the `man grep` page-

> -E, --extended- 
>   Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression (ERE, see below).  (-E is specified by POSIX.)

That should solve your problem since it forces grep to expand the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Also another way to achieve the same without grep :

```
if [[ $git_message=~ $commit_regex ]] 
then
    echo "$error_msg"
    exit 1;
fi
```

Also : If the commit it "gh-1234" is mandated to be at the start of the message , you should add `^` in your regex.

Comment: O, but I don't want to check the $error_msg agains the regex. I would like to check the git commit

Comment: Yeah , of course , it would work against the git commit also if the commit has chars in the form of  `gh-1234`.I just took the error_msg as an example as it too had the "gh-1111" entry.